# copying the returned value of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having issues with figuring out how to copy the value that is returned when z == 2 into the z == 3 elseif in the loop function.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that when I print the row in the  z == 3 piece, I am calling the row function again causing the random id to be generated.

```
import datetime
import random
import string

def date():
    date1 = datetime.date.today()
    return date1.strftime('%Y%m%d')

def loops():
    # User defined input


    # new file create
    import os
    os.path.abspath('fdc/')
    filename = str(prefix1 + date() + '.txt')

    # row loop
    z = int(0)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        # howmany variable no longer exists because there will be 15 lines - 1 for each scenario
        while z < 3:
            if z == 1:
                row()
            elif z == 2:
                row2 = str(row())
                row3 = row2
            elif z == 3:
                print row3
            else:
                row()
            f.write(str(row()))
            z += 1
        f.write(str(trailer()))
        f.close()


def rand_char(y):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(y))


def trailer():
    trailer1 = str("X").ljust(20, "X") + str("0").ljust(8, "0") + date().ljust(8, " ") + str(" ").ljust(413, " ") + \
               str('\n').ljust(1, " ")[:1]
    # print trailer1
    return trailer1


# End of line 1 - ASCII 0A {LF}
eoline = str('\n').ljust(1, " ")[:1]


def row():
    # FDI Internal Merchant ID Generation
    fdimerch_id = ((prefix1 + date() + str(random.randint(0, 50000)) + str(rand_char(10))).rjust(20, " "))[:20]
    row1 = fdimerch_id + eoline
    return  row1

prefix1 = str(raw_input("Enter a prefix:"))
email = str(raw_input("Enter an email: "))

loops()
```

Comment: You will never get to the z == 3 part because the while loop only runs while z is less than 3

Comment: `my_row = row()`, and after that `f.write(my_row)`?

Comment: Why do you have a while loop at all? What's the point in incrementing z and then doing things based on the value of z when you can just write those instructions regularly?

Comment: @Kevin eventually it will have 15 rows of data, using the while loop was what seemed like the best way to control the rows

Comment: As Peter pointed out, the z == 3 case is never reached. Your while loop terminates before this happens, however at the end of elif z == 2 case, row3 appears to be what you want. Note, though, that the only calls to row() that end up being written to your output file are from outside of the if/elif/elif/else case (the call nested inside f.write()). As written, the other calls to row() are never used (and in the z == 1 and else cases, the return value of row() is not even saved to a variable).